# AutoFS fails to mount Samba CIFS share

Tags: mount, cifs, autofs

I have a CentOS 7 server named `server1.example.com` using Samba to share `/srv/samba/share`. `//server1.example.com/share` is the path to the share. I am not able to get CentOS clients to mount `//server1.example.com/share` on `/mnt/myShare` using AutoFS.

- AutoFS is active and running on both the CentOS clients and server.
- Both Firewalld and Iptables are disabled on both the CentOS clients and server.
- SELinux is disabled on both the CentOS clients and server.
- The permissions of /srv/samba/share and /mnt/myShare are 777.
- CentOS clients are able to mount the share as CIFS using the mount command.
- CentOS clients are able to mount the share as CIFS using /etc/fstab.
- CentOS clients are able to mount an NFS share using AutoFS.

The CentOS client has the following configuration.

/etc/auto.master

> /mnt  /etc/auto.cifs  --timeout=60 --ghost

/etc/auto.cifs

> myShare  -fstype=cifs,username=myUsername,password=myPassword ://server1.example.com/share

The mount command shows that AutoFS wants to mount /etc/auto.cifs.

> ~]# mount
>
> /etc/auto.cifs on /mnt

However, AutoFS is not mounting `//server1.example.com/share` on `/mnt/myShare`. I am unsure what needs to be done for AutoFS to mount the share on the CentOS clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a few days to figure this out, so I just wanted to share the things I discovered, in case others have a hard time with AutoFS.

- Ensure you can manually mount the share using the mount command
- Ensure AutoFS is active and running on both the client and server.
- In the /etc/auto.master file, ensure the first field contains the client mount point, such as /mnt.
- Ensure the permissions of /etc/auto.your-map is -rw-r--r-- (644).
- If using Samba and CIFS, ensure smb is active and running on the server.
- If using NFS, ensure NFS is active and running on both the client and server.
- If possible, disable Firewalld and Iptables on both the client and server.
- If possible, disable SELinux on both the client and server.
- On the client, list the mount point, which will trigger AutoFS to automount the share.
- Add OPTION="--debug" to /etc/sysconfig/autofs to add debugging events to /var/log/messages.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed checklist. I'll just add that I confirmed every step but the last, and discovered that on debian-based systems you'll need to add the `debug` option in `/etc/autofs.conf`--which in my case told me that kerberos was using the wrong filename for the ticket cache (which problem is still unsolved...)

Answer (score 0):

in `/etc/auto.cifs`, specifying the password can lead to an auth failure (NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE) if:

- password contains `$`, even escaped one. The `$` sign is simply removed
- password is specified using quote `'`. It looks like autofs is understanding the quote as a password part

Here is my working `auto.cifs` file :

> MOUNTNAME -fstype=cifs,rw,credentials=/root/.cifs_credentials ://SERVER_FQDN/SHARENAME

and the credentials file:

> username=login
>
> password=pass

my server is running sles12

Comment: I took the liberty of cleaning up the formatting a lit bit, also clipped out the "thanks" bit, we normally leave out conversational bits in answers. If you want to know more about formatting feel free to take a look in the help section: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: If you are using Kerberos for authentication you can even reuse the Kerberos ticket so that no additional credentials have to be provided (SSO). [Here's](https://superuser.com/a/1241316/248359) a description how to achieve this.